# How to not overlap pins on a static map view - line markers available?

Tags: mapbox-static-maps

We are trying to put together a static map for a PDF report that shows various properties / some within a mile, some outside. The zoom level is automated so for the below it's automating to 13... but the pins are overlapping. Does anyone know if there is a better way to have a more aerial overview version so the pins do not overlap or like Mapquest does, allow for the line pointing to the location but push the icon out a little so it doesn't overlap?

Example of what we are seeing

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x400&mapType=road&markers=color%3Ared%7Clabel%3AS%7C33.6317725,-117.6969768&markers=color%3A0x4196B7%7Clabel%3A1%7C33.6322778,-117.6960885%7C&markers=color%3A0x4196B7%7Clabel%3A2%7C33.6326150,-117.6955520%7C&markers=color%3A0x4196B7%7Clabel%3A3%7C33.6347943,-117.6941389%7C&markers=color%3A0x4196B7%7Clabel%3A4%7C33.6336735,-117.7007817%7C&markers=color%3A0x4196B7%7Clabel%3A5%7C33.6332321,-117.7035214%7C&markers=color%3A0x4196B7%7Clabel%3A6%7C33.6233070,-117.7093238%7C&markers=color%3A0x1FCD8B%7Clabel%3A1%7C33.6309915,-117.6972705%7C&markers=color%3A0x1FCD8B%7Clabel%3A2%7C33.6318524,-117.6953471%7C&markers=color%3A0x1FCD8B%7Clabel%3A3%7C33.6327322,-117.6995393%7C&markers=color%3A0x1FCD8B%7Clabel%3A4%7C33.6339440,-117.6983970%7C&markers=color%3A0x1FCD8B%7Clabel%3A5%7C33.6347855,-117.6973085%7C&markers=color%3A0x1FCD8B%7Clabel%3A6%7C33.6284267,-117.6953303%7C&markers=color%3A0x1FCD8B%7Clabel%3A7%7C33.6311075,-117.6922050%7C&markers=color%3A0x1FCD8B%7Clabel%3A8%7C33.6290220,-117.6933655%7C&markers=color%3A0x1FCD8B%7Clabel%3A9%7C33.6346083,-117.7008129%7C&markers0=color%3A0x1FCD8B%7Clabel%3A0%7C33.6355780,-117.6941370%7C&markers=color%3A0x723F9F%7Clabel%3A1%7C33.6318524,-117.6953471%7C&markers=color%3A0x723F9F%7Clabel%3A2%7C33.6346572,-117.6965128%7C&markers=color%3A0x723F9F%7Clabel%3A3%7C33.6390697,-117.7042227%7C&markers=color%3Agray%7Clabel%3A4%7C33.6368970,-117.7072850%7C&markers=color%3A0x723F9F%7Clabel%3A5%7C33.6430958,-117.6904777%7C&markers=color%3A0x723F9F%7Clabel%3A6%7C33.6183837,-117.6864815%7C&markers=color%3A0x723F9F%7Clabel%3A7%7C33.6441780,-117.7110758%7C&markers=color%3A0x723F9F%7Clabel%3A8%7C33.6501767,-117.7006036%7C&markers=color%3A0x723F9F%7Clabel%3A9%7C33.6544377,-117.6917786%7C&markers0=color%3A0x723F9F%7Clabel%3A0%7C33.6115544,-117.6810276%7C&mapid=f6fc6ed0d73da1da&key=AIzaSyDIHxjRfDmv076b4dkIUJABF0_ntuHKoiQ

tried changing zoom levels but it cuts the pins off